# Webview (live video stream) showing blank screen coming from Activity B to Activity A android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-webview

I am creating a live streaming application. There are 2 activities. Activity-A contains a button which direct to Webview-Activity-B (which has the webview). The live stream video (http://192.168.22.3:80/play) content is available when I go initially to Webview-Activity-B, but when I go back to Activity-A and then go to Webview-Activity-B It shows a blank white screen in the webview. Is this something I should work with OnResume/ onPause/ onSaveInstanceState/ onRestoreInstanceState.

Comment: I used this line of code webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK); 
and It works fine. But the screen gets frozen after a while.


(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24789299/android-webview-save-state)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34572748/how-to-make-android-webview-clear-cache Solved it

Comment: It was crashing the web view again. so i added webViewCam.stopLoading();
        webViewCam.loadUrl(" "); in onBackPressed() . Now it works successfully.